# Info about Image in C# WPF

Tags: wpf

first:
do u know why I can't get the method FromFile?
ex: I can't write  Image.FromFile

second:
Do u know how I could get the Image Dimensions in c# WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get dimensions of image

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\Images\Image1.JPG"));
double width = image.Width;
double height = image.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the FromFile static method is from System.Drawing namespace. In wpf you've to set the image source using the `Source` property. [Take a look at this example in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx)
2. You can use the Height and Width property for setting the dimensions